# Unknown column in where clause while parsing csv to update table

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am parsing a CSV file to add records to a table. this is how I do it.

```
public function parse_csv($file) {

        $this->load->library('CSVReader');
        $csvData = $this->csvreader->parse_file($file);


        foreach($csvData as $key => $row) {
            $data_n[$key] = array(
                'mf_date' => $row['mf_date'],
                'mf_student_id' => $row['mf_student_id'],
                'mf_sender' => $row['mf_sender'],
                'mf_amount' => $row['mf_amount'],
                'mf_trx_id' => $row['mf_trx_id'],
                );
            $this->db->insert('monthly_fee', $data_n[$key]);
            $this->student_model->update_monthly_due($row['mf_student_id'], $row['mf_amount']);
        }
    }
```

I wish to update another table where there is three columns

```
1)md_student_id //unique
2)md_due
3)md_paid
```

I want to update that table while uploading the csv where mf_student_id and md_student_id matches with the model function below.

```
public function update_monthly_due($mf_student_id, $mf_amount)
    {   
        $this->db->select('mf_student_id');
        $this->db->from('monthly_fee');
        $this->db->join('monthly_due', 'monthly_due.md_student_id = monthly_fee.mf_student_id');
        $sql = "UPDATE monthly_due set md_due = md_due - " . $mf_amount . ", md_paid = md_paid + " . $mf_amount . " WHERE md_student_id = " . $mf_student_id;
        $this->db->query($sql);
    }
```

But when I upload a csv it generates the following error.

```
Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'MCS20145B41' in 'where clause'

UPDATE monthly_due set md_due = md_due - 5500, md_paid = md_paid + 5500 WHERE md_student_id = MCS20145B41

Filename: F:\xampp\htdocs\student\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

What I am doing wrong?!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should replace this line as follow

```
$sql = "UPDATE monthly_due set md_due = md_due - " . $mf_amount . ", md_paid = md_paid + " . $mf_amount . " WHERE md_student_id = '" . $mf_student_id . "'";
```

take attention to the end of this line

Answer (score 1):

Why not use **CI's active record** instead of **raw SQL queries**.
When doing it do it the **correct way**. This below:

**Change this,**

```
$sql = "UPDATE monthly_due set md_due = md_due - " . $mf_amount . ", md_paid = md_paid + " . $mf_amount . " WHERE md_student_id = " . $mf_student_id;
$this->db->query($sql);
```

**To,**

```
$this->db->where('md_student_id', $mf_student_id);
$this->db->set('md_due', "md_due - $mf_amount", FALSE);
$this->db->set('md_paid', "md_paid + $mf_amount", FALSE);
$this->db->update('monthly_due');
```

**Explanation:**

The reason this works is because the third (optional) FALSE parameter tells CodeIgniter not to protect the generated query with backticks ('). This means that the generated SQL will be:

```
UPDATE monthly_due set md_due = md_due - 5500, md_paid = md_paid + 5500 WHERE md_student_id = "MCS20145B41"
```